# make dmrshark error : sqrtf@@GLIBC2.0 undefined reference

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I want to make *dmrshark* from https://github.com/nonoo/dmrshark ,but when I make that, it gives an error while making it. Can anybody help me?

Error message:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/m/sdr/dmrshark/libs/aprs'
gcc  -DDMRSHARK_BUILD -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -O0 -DGITHASH=\"ac306a84b6ed4a4167e272f05b32dad200715574\" -DDEFAULTCONFIG="<config/defaults.h>" -DAPPCONFIGFILE=\"/home/m/sdr/dmrshark//config/app/dmrshark.h\" -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -DARCH_X86 -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char -Wno-unused-result -DAMBEDECODEVOICE -DMP3ENCODEVOICE  -I../../make/..  dmrshark-dmrshark.o  -L../../make/../libs -Wl,--start-group  -lbase-dmrshark  -lconfig-dmrshark  -ldaemon-dmrshark  -lcomm-dmrshark  -lremotedb-dmrshark  -ldmrpacket-dmrshark  -lcoding-dmrshark  -lvoicestreams-dmrshark  -laprs-dmrshark  -lpcap  -lsnmp  -lmysqlclient  -lpthread  -lwebsockets  -lmbe  -lmp3lame -Wl,--end-group  -lglib-2.0   -o dmrshark-build-ac306a
/usr/bin/ld: ../../make/../libs/libvoicestreams-dmrshark.a(voicestreams-process-dmrshark.o): undefined reference to symbol 'sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.0'
//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [dmrshark-build-ac306a] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/m/sdr/dmrshark/build/dmrshark'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you sure you have installed all the required dependencies?

Comment: @edwinksl : yes ... i install this package ibglib2.0-dev,libpcap-dev,libsnmp-dev,libmysqlclient-dev,libwebsockets,libmp3lame-dev and mbelib ....

Comment: `DSO missing from command line` usually means you missed a library (in this case `-lm`); however I would expect `-std=gnu99` to use a builtin `sqrtf` in this case. FWIW it appears to build fine on my 14.04 64-bit machine, so perhaps it's something specific to 32-bit platforms? BTW exactly what platform / Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @steeldriver : 14.04 ... are you sure it's with the latest updates ? I had no luck with Ubuntu **14.04.4** - 64 : A missing *@GLIBC_2.2.5 . Nor with 16.04 - 64 ... But Ubuntu 12.04.5 - 64  could create the executable `dmrshark-build-ac306a` , etc.

Comment: Oops sorry - there were errors, I just didn't notice them because `make` didn't stop. Please ignore that comment.

Comment: @steeldriver: its ubuntu 32bit 14.04 LTS

Comment: @KnudLarsen: realy ubuntu 12.04.5 -64 coulld creat dmrshark??? Did you try it?

Comment: @Ali Begloo : 12.04.5 - 64 →  Yes, no serious issues . The executables { aprsmsgparse, dmrshark-build-ac306a, hytera-gps-but, hytera-gps-trig, mbetest, (motorola.sms-)test } were created.

Comment: @KnudLarsen: thanks , i try ubuntu12.04.5 ... but which package you installd?... which source???

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04.5 - 64, dmrshark :

```
sudo apt-get install g++ git cmake libglib2.0-dev libpcap-dev libsnmp-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmp3lame-dev
```

Sources ...

```
git clone https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets.git
git clone https://github.com/szechyjs/mbelib.git
git clone https://github.com/nonoo/dmrshark.git
```

Build the libraries libwebsockets, mbelib, and install with `sudo make install`.

`cd dmrshark/`, 1) Move away the folder files/ : `mv files/ ../`, i.e. the very simple Makefile´s will try to 'make' anything, also data files, and thus fail. 2) `cp build/Makefile tests/` . (A missing Makefile in tests/.)

Next : `make` ( The `make install` fails. But you have the executable´s, and can use them as is.)

Or get a copy here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOFQ5MG9aZkxrY3c/view?usp=sharing

---

Comment: thanks ... i try it in ubuntu 12.04. -64 and compile dmrshark successful. thank you a lot.